# How can I merge free space partition with primary ntfs partition using Gparted in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I need help partitioning my hard drive properly. An image of my gparted is here:
[image]

My goal is to merge a free space partition into my primary ntfs partition which has Windows 7 on it so i can dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.

Refer to gparted image: sda1 is Windows 7 and sda5 is ubuntu 14.04. sda6 **was** ubuntu 12.04 but i just deleted that partition and now it is free space. I want to be able to use that space for windows 7. The sda3 is my windows recovery drive.

Should I merge sda6 with sda1 or just make it as a folder inside Win7? I'm expecting to merge it but I don't know how. Help please!

Comment: ...a screenshot would've been nice.

Comment: even a paste from fdisk or parted `-l`

Comment: Attach a screenshot of gparted, we need to actually see the partition layout

Comment: You might consider looking at the following article for an example -- [Moving Space Between Partitions](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=moving-space-between-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you need to do is to shrink the extended partition in order to create more unallocated space outside of it, (perhaps) move the extended partition to the right so that the unallocated space is on the left and next to the Windows partition, then extend the Windows partition into the unallocated space.  Just note that the "left and right" directions will only be correct if the Windows partition is immediately to the left of the extended partition (as I would expect).  If you can post a screenshot of Gparted's view of your disk, I'm sure that people will be able to give very specific advice.

Comment: Ok I just added a link to the gparted image. Hopefully the question is more clear now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to shuffle the partitions around - slide sda5 to the right of the extended partition, then shrink the extended partition to bring the free space outside.  I think this puts the free space on the left of the extended partition.  If this is indeed the case, you can then extend sda1 using the free space.  If this isn't totally accurate, you need to move the partitions around until the free space is adjacent to the Windows partition.  The link provided by Curtis Gedak seems to provide good information on the re-arranging process.

Comment: Thanks. That link did help. I'm still getting some errors with Gparted but I think it might be better to ask those questions on the Gparted forums.